# Setting editmode to incell RadGrid in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik, radgrid

I am trying to set the editmode to incell in Telerik's Radgrid. There are examples online, however they are all in HTML. How can you do this in asp?

P.S. I have a grid with data that is automatically retrieved from a database. What I want to do is be able to edit each cell individually and save them to the database.

I can't figure out how to get anything to edit. Here is the C# and aspx code.

aspx:

```
    <body> 
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
</asp:ScriptManager> 
<div> 



    <telerik:RadGrid ID="GrdConfig" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" 
        EnableLinqExpressions="False" oncolumncreated="GrdConfig_ColumnCreated" 
        CssClass="MyRadGridCssClass" AllowPaging="True"> 
        <ClientSettings> 
            <Resizing AllowColumnResize="True" /> 
            <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" /> 
        </ClientSettings> 
        <MasterTableView> 
            <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings> 

            <RowIndicatorColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column"> 
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle> 
            </RowIndicatorColumn> 

            <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column"> 
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle> 
            </ExpandCollapseColumn> 

            <EditFormSettings> 
                <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column"></EditColumn> 
            </EditFormSettings> 

        </MasterTableView> 

        <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False"></FilterMenu> 
    </telerik:RadGrid> 

</div> 
</form>
```

C#:

```
    public partial class Configurations : System.Web.UI.Page 
{ 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 

             ** Code to extract data from database goes here**


        GrdConfig.DataSource = data; 
        GrdConfig.DataBind(); 

        GridGroupByExpression expression = GridGroupByExpression.Parse("ConfigFile[Config File:] Group by ConfigFile"); 
        GrdConfig.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Add(expression); 

        GridColumn cConfig = GrdConfig.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("ConfigFile"); 

        cConfig.Visible = false; 

        GrdConfig.Rebind(); 

    } 


    protected void GrdConfig_ColumnCreated(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (e.Column is GridGroupSplitterColumn) 
        { 
            e.Column.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(1); 
            e.Column.HeaderStyle.Font.Size = FontUnit.Point(1); 
            e.Column.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(1); 
            e.Column.ItemStyle.Font.Size = FontUnit.Point(1); 
            e.Column.Resizable = false; 
        } 
    } 

    protected void GrdConfig_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (e.Item is GridGroupHeaderItem) 
        { 
            GridGroupHeaderItem groupHeader = (GridGroupHeaderItem)e.Item; 
            groupHeader.Font.Bold = true; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: There is no Telerik control for ASP. They are for ASP.Net. You cannot edit each cell individually; however, you can edit one row at a time.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I suppose you mean the following demo:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/clienteditbatchupdates/defaultcs.aspx

If this is the case, I'm afraid you can't just switch to such mode because it this is achieved with custom code.